# What does '^@' mean in vim?

Tags: bash, vim, cat, playready, pssh

When I cat a file in bash I get the following:

```
$ cat /tmp/file 
microsoft
```

When I view the same file in vim I get the following:

```
^@m^@i^@c^@r^@o^@s^@o^@f^@t^@
```

How can I identify and remove these "non-printable" characters. What does '^@' mean in vim??

(Just a piece of background information: the file was created by base 64 decoding and cutting from the pssh header of an mpd file for Microsoft Playready)

Comment: I should not that when I type 'ga' in normal mode it does reveal the character: <^@>  0,  Hex 00,  Octal 000

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you see is Vim's visual representation of *unprintable characters*. It is explained at `:help 'isprint'`:

> ```
> Non-printable characters are displayed with two characters:
>     0 -  31   "^@" - "^_"
>    32 - 126   always single characters
>      127      "^?"
>   128 - 159   "~@" - "~_"
>   160 - 254   "| " - "|~"
>      255      "~?"
> ```

Therefore, `^@` stands for a *null byte* = 0x00. These (and other non-printable characters) can come from various sources, but in your case it's an ...

#### encoding issue

If you clearly observe your output in Vim, *every second byte is a null byte*; in between are the expected characters. This is a clear indication that the file uses a *multibyte encoding* (`utf-16`, big endian, no byte order mark to be precise), and Vim did not properly detect that, and instead opened the file as `latin1` or so (whereas things worked out properly in the terminal).

To fix this, you can either explicitly specify the encoding:

```
:edit ++enc=utf-16 /tmp/file
```

Or tweak the `'fileencodings'` option, so that Vim can automatically detect this. However, be aware that ambiguities (as in your case) make this prone to fail:

> For an empty file or a file with only ASCII characters most encodings
>     will work and the first entry of 'fileencodings' will be used (except
>     "ucs-bom", which requires the BOM to be present).

That's why a *byte order mark* (BOM) is recommended for 16-bit encodings; but that assumes that you have control over the output encoding.

Answer (score 4):

`^@` is Vim's representation of a null byte. The `^` indicates a non-printable control character, with the following ASCII character indicating
which control character it is.

```
^@ == 0 (NUL)
^A == 1
^B == 2
...
^H == 8
^K == 11
...
^Z == 26
^[ == 27
^\ == 28
^] == 29
^^ == 30
^_ == 31
^? == 127
```

9 and 10 aren't escaped because they are Tab and Line Feed respectively.

32 to 126 are printable ASCII characters (starting with Space).

Comment: thanks for your answer. It is direct and to the point. The answer I accepted gave me a bit more background information which is why I accepted it. However I have up-voted your answer as well.

Comment: No problem; Ingo clearly answers your question in a more useful manner,